# Do somenthing when scroll = 0 and something else when >< 0 with jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, offset, scrolltop

I was wondering if it's possible to make a div change his width depending the scroll position. I'm trying this:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    var img = $("#lip");
    middle = $('#middle').offset();
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    if(y < middle.top){
        img.animate({width: "400px"}, 1000);
    }else if(y > middle.top){
        img.animate({width: "100px"}, 1000);
    }
});
```

The problem of this code is that only one "if" work, if I delete one, the other works, but I want them working together!

The HTML is something like this:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="lip">
        <img src="image.png" />
    </div>
</div>

<div id="middle">
    blablabla
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand your expected behaviour here??? `only one "if" work, if I delete one, the other works, but I want them working together!` ???  `if(y != 0){...}` ?!

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't speak english. What I want: When scroll = 0, then "width:400px" // when scroll != 0, then "width:100px"

Comment: So you could use: `if(y === 0){img.stop().animate({width: "400px"}, 1000);}else{img.stop().animate({width: "100px"}, 1000);}` but be aware than you should debounce scroll event: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should write

```
if(y < middle.top){
    img.animate({width: "400px"}, 1000);
}else{
    img.animate({width: "100px"}, 1000);
}
```

you should add before the "if"

```
console.log(y, middle.top)
```

and open your JS console to view thoses values while playing with the scroll bar

Comment: Didn't work. the "if(y < middle.top)" works, but the "else" is ignored when I keep scrolling. Sorry about the poor english.

Comment: what console.log(y, middle.top) returns ?